# Is "reveal himself as" and "reveal that he's" the same thing?

Tags: meaning

I am wondering if these two are synonymous in most cases. I am also not 100% sure that "reveal himself as" means about the same thing as "reveal that he's", but I think they are. They should mean the same thing, but who knows?

For example:

> He revealed himself as the double agent who leaked everything.
>
> He revealed that he's the double agent who leaked everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're very close in meaning, but "revealed himself" sounds more dramatic: it suggests that he did something more direct and noticeable (made an announcement, for example) whereas "revealed that he" suggests something a little lower-key.

But these are only nuances: either could be used in either case.

Comment: Yes. Clark Kent would *reveal himself* to Lois Lane as Superman by undoing his work clothes and showing his costume underneath. On the other hand, Kent would *reveal* that he was Superman by simply having a conversation with her about it.